# Polymorphism behavior

Tags: polymorphism, system-verilog

Could someone help explain this behavior difference? Shouldn't functions that are virtual be always virtual? Does it matter where it is made virtual-parent/child class.

Variant 1:

```
module test;
   class A;
      virtual function void showMsg(int val);
         $display("This is A");
      endfunction
   endclass
   class B extends A;
       function void showMsg(int val);
         $display("This is B, val = %0d", val);
      endfunction
   endclass
   class C extends B;
      function void showMsg(int val);
         $display("This is C, val=%0d", val+1);
      endfunction
   endclass
   initial begin
      A a;
      B b;
      C c;
      b = new();
      a = b;
     a.showMsg(1);
      c = new();
      b = c;
     b.showMsg(7); 
   end
endmodule
```

Variant 2:

```
module test;
   class A;
       function void showMsg(int val);
         $display("This is A");
      endfunction
   endclass
   class B extends A;
       virtual function void showMsg(int val);
         $display("This is B, val = %0d", val);
      endfunction
   endclass
   class C extends B;
      function void showMsg(int val);
         $display("This is C, val=%0d", val+1);
      endfunction
   endclass
   initial begin
      A a;
      B b;
      C c;
      b = new();
      a = b;
     a.showMsg(1);
      c = new();
      b = c;
     b.showMsg(7); 
   end
endmodule
```

Variant1 results-

> This is B, val = 1 This is C, val=8

Variant2 results-

> This is A This is C, val=8

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3RMZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In variant 2, `A::showMsg` is non-virtual. The code calling `a.showMsg` must behave as non-virtual because is has no knowledge the class will be extended. That means `A::showMsg` could have a completely different prototype from `B::showMsg` if you wanted (i.e. a different number of argument). But once `B::showMsg` is declared virtual, all derived methods are virtual and must have the same prototype.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the `virtual A::showMsg` then it can be overridden in any derived class. In this case it does not matter if `B::showMsg` is also *virtual* or not.

```
class A;
virtual showMsg();
..
class B extends A;
    showMsg();
class C extends B;
    showMsg();

a = c;
a.showMsg() --> calls C::showMsg();
a = b;
a.showMsg() --> calls B::showMsg();
```

However, if *only* `B::showMsg` is *virtual*, then `A::showMsg` will not be overridden and any reference to it through the base class will call that function from `A`. However, it could be re-implemented in any class derived from `B`. However, using `B` as a base class will call the new implementation of the function.

```
class A;
    showMsg();
..
class B extends A;
    virtual showMsg();
class C extends B;
    showMsg();

a = c; (or a = b;)
a.showMsg() --> calls A::showMsg();
b = c;
b.showMsg() --> calls C:showMsg();
```

you are missing one more interesting case you want to explore:

```
 a = c;
 a.showMsg(13);
```

Comment: It seems like once virtual, always virtual, is not really true. The "virtual"ity really starts from the point within the inheritance tree where it is declared as virtual the first time.

Comment: virtuality is inherited in all the derived classes (but not before). this is what i said in the examples.